# WebSphere: Alternative to deprecated method WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection

Tags: java, websphere, oracle-aq

I am using Oracle AQ within WAS. It requires an OracleConnection instance to work. Currently I am obtaining the connection via the deprecated method `WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection`

```
Class.forName("oracle.AQ.AQOracleDriver")
val ctx = new InitialContext()
val datasource = ctx.lookup("jdbc/MessageManagerDB").asInstanceOf[DataSource]
val wasConnection = datasource.getConnection.asInstanceOf[WSJdbcConnection]
val nativeConnection = WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection(wasConnection)
AQDriverManager.createAQSession(nativeConnection.asInstanceOf[Connection])
```

Is there a non-deprecated alternative to this method?

(ps, code sample is scala, but this question tagged java, as it is regarding the WAS Java API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WSCallHelper](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/rsadapter/WSCallHelper.html).getNativeConnection

Answer (score 0):

also, if the connection implements java.sql.Wrapper, you should be able to use to get the underlying connection.

Comment: Wrapper.unwrap does not guarantee a direct reference to the underlying instance: "an object that implements the interface. May be a proxy for the actual implementing object."  WebSphere Application Server returns proxies.